# Do you use <hr> in your HTML?

Tags: wordpress, html, semantic-markup, web-standards

Use of `<hr>` is still valid in HTML5 but do you think it's semantically correct and it's a part of content?

**Are you using it in your projects?**

I find it diffult when to add any `<hr>` we need to go to html code every time. using `hr` is mixing presentation with content.

Wordpress WYSIWYG editor doesn't have button for `<hr>` so if i use it then non technical client would not be able to add it if the add/remove/re-organize content.

Comment: What on earth does Wordpress have to do with this question?

Comment: Wordpress WYSIWYG editor doesn't have button for `<hr>` so if i use it then non technical client would not be able to add it if the add/remove/re-organize content.

Comment: Ok, what on earth does Wordpress's WYSIWYG editor have to do with this question?

Comment: Added a link in my reply that might help you.

Answer (score 3):

Yup - still use it for breaking up sections of long text - not for anything else really.

If you can still see this after they so kindly closed your question - as it's to do with Wordpress really and not HR tags - here's a link that might help you out of the problem. (and to yet another mystery stackexchange that I didn't know about.

https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/6033/get-a-button-for-hr-in-the-editor

Answer (score 2):

I've been using this once again lately, simply because it is easy to understand what's going on for another developer reading your code:

```
<h1>My title</h1>
<hr>
<p>My paragraph</p>
```

It still is definitely more of a styling than anything else. If you want to be strict about separating style from (semantic) markup you could think of using something like  with a border-bottom in CSS for example.

I think readability counts and that it works fine the way it does, even in HTML5.

That being said, I *barely* use it at all.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I think it's correct to use `hr` in html5, but only in long texts as a kind of page-break. I would never use an `hr` to divide functionally different sections of the page. 
For me, a proper use would be in a wiki, which is primarily text based in much the same way as the earliest html pages were. It's more that many modern sites favor a design with shorter blocks or even paged text that `hr` tags don't seem very useful anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting article: http://html5doctor.com/small-hr-element/

> I learned `<hr>` actually means "end of one section, start of another", which is the same semantically as `</section><section>`. Because elements like `<section>` already indicate this intrinsically, `<hr>` is more for thematic breaks, such as separating different topics within a section of prose, or between scenes in a novel. However you can use it anywhere you can use a `<p>`.

but I don't use it anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use it if there is a shift in topic or theme in your content that isn't already being marked by something else semantically (Heading or a new section).